# Interacting with a an app from another JVM using javax.accessibility

Tags: java

I am trying to interact with an java swing app using [java accessibility utilities](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-desktop-accessibility-downloads.html).  The java accessibility guide says that

> For an assistive technology to work with a Java application, load it
> into the same JVM as the Java application to which it is providing
> access. This is done through the use of the assistive_technologies
> property.

and

> The Monkey class is in the examples/Monkey directory included with
> this release of the Java Accessibility Utilities. Before you can run it, you need to set up your
> environment appropriately by following these instructions:
>
> ```
> Copy jaccess.jar and jaccess-examples.jar to the $JDKHOME/jre/lib/ext directory under your JDK1.2 or later
> installation.
> Modify (create one if it doesn't exist) your $JDKHOME/jre/lib/accessibility.properties file to include the 
> following line:
>
> assistive_technologies=Monkey
> ```
>
> By following the instructions above, Monkey will automatically be started any time you start a Java application. For example, you can run the SwingSet demo that comes as part of the demonstration applications for Swing.

I have copied jaccess-examples.jar to my jre folder (C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\lib\ext),
jaccess.jar was there already, added to accessibility.properties file in (C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\lib) the line assistive_technologies=Monkey but nothing happens when launching a java swing application. How can i make it work?

To note that it does actually work if Monkey starts in the same JVM as the app it needs to access even without modifying accessibility.properties file.

Comment: I am not sure why is this a question. The doc says you cannot do that. You have not explained why you want to (From another jvm).

Comment: I have an app which starts on system startup and i want to interact with its controls. I tried access bridge explorer https://github.com/google/access-bridge-explorer which uses the java access bridge which exposes the accessibility options of java apps and it does show that it is possible. Now i would like to get the same functionality on a smaller scale(just this one app) using java code.

Comment: I've gotten around this by using JNA to load and use the functions from WindowsAccessBridge-64.dll located in jre/bin folder.

Comment: Do you have an example how did you do it?

Comment: I achieved to see the GUI tree of an app in jaccesswalker (Java 11 replacement for Monkey, deployed with JDK11) after running jabswitcher -enable. I expected once this works to see the same GUI tree details also in MS tools like Inspect or UI-automation, but unfortunately I don't. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I am not familiar with Inspect, but it probably does not work because it is made for Windows apps, Java ones are a bit different.

Comment: Yes, I probably falsely assumed, that enabling Windows Access Bridge will make Microsoft UI automation to see Java Gui elements. The more I read, I see, those are separate things. My usecase is the same as yours, automating Java GUI from Java, but from another JVM, so I'm struggling using JNA directly with windowsaccessbridge-64.dll. I'm completely new to JNA, so I'd be glad, if you could share how you did it :). Best regards.

Comment: As per https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md i loaded WindowsAccessBridge-64.dll

Answer (score 2):

```
//load WindowsAccessBridge-64.dll

    import com.sun.jna.Library;
    import com.sun.jna.Native;
    import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef;
    import com.sun.jna.ptr.PointerByReference;

    public interface WindowsAccessBridge extends Library {

        //Load the .dll using JNA
        WindowsAccessBridge INSTANCE = Native.load("windowsaccessbridge-64", WindowsAccessBridge.class);


        //declare some functions from the .dll

        void Windows_run();

        boolean isJavaWindow(WinDef.HWND window);

        boolean getAccessibleContextFromHWND(WinDef.HWND target, WinDef.LONGByReference vmID, PointerByReference accessibleContext);

        boolean getAccessibleContextInfo(WinDef.LONG vmID, Pointer accessibleContext, ABPackages.AccessibleContextInfo.ByReference info);

    }



 //load custom user32.dll, the user32 provided by JNA does not have the ChangeWindowMessageFilter function

    import com.sun.jna.Native;
    import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.WNDENUMPROC;
    import com.sun.jna.ptr.PointerByReference;
    import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;

    public interface UUser32 extends StdCallLibrary {

        UUser32 INSTANCE = Native.load("user32", UUser32.class);

        boolean ChangeWindowMessageFilter(int message, int flag);

    }

    //to get window messages you need a message pump
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser;
    import static com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.WM_COPYDATA;
    import static com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.WM_USER;

    public class WindowMessagePump extends Thread {
        //get a WAB instance
        private final WindowsAccessBridge wab = WindowsAccessBridge.INSTANCE;
        //get a custom user32 instance
        private final UUser32 uUser32 = UUser32.INSTANCE;
        // the user32 provided by JNA
        private final User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            uUser32.ChangeWindowMessageFilter(WM_COPYDATA, 1);
            for (int i = WM_USER + 1; i < 0xfff; i++) {
                uUser32.ChangeWindowMessageFilter(i, 1);
            }
            wab.Windows_run();
            WinUser.MSG msg = new WinUser.MSG();
            while (user32.GetMessage(msg, null, 0, 0) > 0) {
                user32.TranslateMessage(msg);
                user32.DispatchMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }

    //you also need some structures to get the needed information 

    import com.sun.jna.Structure;

    public class ABPackages {

        static final int MAX_STRING_SIZE = 1024;
        static final int SHORT_STRING_SIZE = 256;

        @Structure.FieldOrder({"name", "description", "role", "role_en_US", "states", "states_en_US", "indexInParent",
                "childrenCount", "x", "y", "width", "height", "accessibleComponent", "accessibleAction",
                "accessibleSelection", "accessibleText", "accessibleInterfaces"})
        public static class AccessibleContextInfo extends Structure {
            public char[] name = new char[MAX_STRING_SIZE];        // the AccessibleName of the object
            public char[] description = new char[MAX_STRING_SIZE]; // the AccessibleDescription of the object
            public char[] role = new char[SHORT_STRING_SIZE];      // localized AccesibleRole string
            public char[] role_en_US = new char[SHORT_STRING_SIZE];
            public char[] states = new char[SHORT_STRING_SIZE];    // localized AccesibleStateSet string (comma separated)
            public char[] states_en_US = new char[SHORT_STRING_SIZE];
            public int indexInParent;                   // index of object in parent
            public int childrenCount;                  // # of children, if any
            public int x;                              // screen x-axis co-ordinate in pixels
            public int y;                              // screen y-axis co-ordinate in pixels
            public int width;                          // pixel width of object
            public int height;                         // pixel height of object
            public int accessibleComponent;            // flags for various additional
            public int accessibleAction;               // Java Accessibility interfaces
            public int accessibleSelection;            // FALSE if this object doesn't
            public int accessibleText;                 // implement the additional interface
            public int accessibleInterfaces;           // new bitfield containing additional interface flags

            public static class ByReference extends AccessibleContextInfo implements Structure.ByReference {
            }

            public static class ByValue extends AccessibleContextInfo implements Structure.ByValue {
            }
        }
    }


    //and now for the implementation
    import com.sun.jna.Native;
    import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.DesktopWindow;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.WindowUtils;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef;
    import com.sun.jna.ptr.PointerByReference;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        //start the message pump
        WindowMessagePump messagePump = new WindowMessagePump();
        messagePump.setDaemon(true);
        messagePump.start();
        //wait a few seconds for the pump to start just in case
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //get an instance of windows access bridge
        WindowsAccessBridge accessBridge = WindowsAccessBridge.INSTANCE;

        //get a list of active windows
        List<DesktopWindow> list = WindowUtils.getAllWindows(true);

        for (DesktopWindow window : list) {
            if (window.getFilePath().contains("the name of the window you are looking for")) {
                WinDef.HWND handle = window.getHWND();
                //check if its a java window
                if (accessBridge.isJavaWindow(handle)) {

                    WinDef.LONGByReference vmID = new WinDef.LONGByReference();
                    PointerByReference accessibleContext = new PointerByReference();

                    boolean getAccessibleContextSuccess = accessBridge.getAccessibleContextFromHWND(handle, vmID, accessibleContext);

                    if(getAccessibleContextSuccess) {
                        ABPackages.AccessibleContextInfo.ByReference contextInfo = new ABPackages.AccessibleContextInfo.ByReference();
                        boolean getContextInfoSuccess = accessBridge.getAccessibleContextInfo(vmID.getValue(), accessibleContext.getValue(), contextInfo);
                        System.out.println("getContextInfoSuccess: " + getContextInfoSuccess);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```